# RSA prime decimal digits

Tags: encryption, rsa, primes, public-key-encryption

In RSA encryption there is multiply of 2 big primes like: `key=bigPrime1*bigPrime2`
I want to know how big is the `key` and `bigPrime`. 
How many digits do they have in a RSA key?

Comment: After 8 months I would expect you to know what is on topic and what is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These days, 1024-bit keys are probably breakable by governments, most people probably use 2048-bit keys, and high-security environments (banks, governments, criminals, terrorists) probably use 4096-bit (or more) keys. We use 2048-bit keys where I work to protect personally-identifiable information (SSN, birthday) in our database.

Comment: In 2010 a 768-bit key was cracked but it took 2 years and the paper says that a 1024-bit would be several thousand times harder, here is the paper http://eprint.iacr.org/2010/006.pdf

Comment: I'm familiar with that paper. But that was a group of academics. I assume the NSA is somewhat ahead of them. And hardware is faster than it was three years ago. Also a dozen professors don't have the budget that the NSA has to throw at a particular factorization. The bottom line is that you should be using something more than 1024-bit RSA if you are serious about crypto.